# PHP - Blogger API date to milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, blogger, milliseconds

I am trying to convert blogger timestamp format to milliseconds and below is my code. Once it is converted to milliseconds and then I further convert the milliseconds to date and time but it displays the **wrong date and time**

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php 
 echo strtotime("2018-02-26T01:52:00-08:00");
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**
1519638720

**Sample Code:**

```
$milliseconds = 1519638720;
$seconds = $milliseconds / 1000;
$date = date("d M Y, D", $seconds);
$seconds = $milliseconds / 1000;
$time = date("g:i a", $seconds);
echo $date.", ".$time;
```

**WRONG OUPUT:** 
18 Jan 1970, Sun, 2:07 pm

Comment: Confused, a timestamp is not in milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to convert the blogger date to milliseconds and the solution to it is adding 0's, i.e 1519638720000 and the output comes somewhat accurate but it is not the right way.

Comment: 1519638720 is not in milliseconds! if you divide it by 1000 gives you `1519638.72` which is `(1519638.72 / 3600) / 24` = 17.58 days.. from 1st of Jan 1970 `18 Jan 1970, Sun, 2:07 pm` ... Not wrong output! What are you expecting?

Comment: Oh okay, I was expecting it to be in milliseconds. So if I multiply 1000 to 1519638720 then the output is **26 Feb 2018, Mon, 9:52 am** So I want to confirm if its the right way ? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: time() and strtotime() returns a timestamp (seconds) from 1st Jan 1970, why do you need to times it by 1000 then divide it by 1000 :/ Your datetime string does not include milliseconds, so I'm not sure what your even trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually I need to store the blogger post published date in milliseconds format. :/ @LawrenceCherone
All I found on googling was converting it to date and time format but 
 did not find anything regarding the milliseconds (except for strtotime). Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165950/discussion-between-topper1309-and-lawrence-cherone).

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake, which you made is that `strtotime` return the count of seconds, so improve like this:

```
$seconds = strtotime("2018-02-26T01:52:00-08:00");
$date = date("d M Y, D", $seconds);
$time = date("g:i a", $seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I want the blogger timestamp to be in milliseconds first and I found the problem as well, if I add 0's to the output, i.e 1519638720000. Then the output is somewhat accurate. But this is not the right way to add 0's and I tried finding solutions  for it but did not find anything @Pavel

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in comments:

> Actually I need to store the blogger post published date in milliseconds format.

Based on that, best choice would be to have PHP version > 7.1 (and not 7.1.3, since it has a bug, see [here](https://3v4l.org/qHbgY)), where microseconds

Create new `DateTime` object:

```php
$now = new DateTime();
```

To output timestamp with microsecond part use format type `U` and `u`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) what they are.

```php
$uSeconds = $now->format('U.u'); //
```

And now store this data in your DB.

---

If you don't have PHP >7.1, then use [`microtime(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), which will return unix timestamp with microseconds part.